# Associating Eclipse's JDT tokenizer's token identifiers with its JDT parser's AST node identifiers

Tags: java, parsing, tokenize, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to find the common ground between Eclipse's JDT tokenizer and its JDT parser.

Details of my code setup are as follows. For tokenizing, I'm using an object of type `PublicScanner` in package `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util`. For parsing a program, I'm using the `ASTParser` object in package `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom`. And I'm comparing the outputs from parser and the tokenizer.

To elaborate on my question. Say my input to the tokenizer and the parser is: `public class Test{}`. Considering only the token `public`, its identifier from the tokenizer is 103, and its `AST` node identifier (using `ASTNode.getNodeType()`) from the `ASTParser` output is 83. So my question here is, whether there exists a method in Eclipse's JDT that helps associate the tokenizer output with the parser output? Or, alternatively, suggestions for how to do this would also be helpful. My understanding is that the tokenizer's and the parser's output are not equivalent as the parser also includes structural information for its nodes. But for some of the tokens/nodes, they can be, like in the case elicited above. Hence, my question's focus is only on the cases when it can be done.